# How can I import a CSV on a GUI and then use other functions to obtain more insightful informations

Tags: python, dataframe, user-interface

As the title, I am trying to import a CSV on a GUI to work on it. Unfortunately an error occurs when I try to launch the second funtion

Here is the code

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
window.title("GUI NTV-TRN")

def first_button_function():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=window,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
    if file != None:
        data = file.read()
        file.close()

def second_button_function():
    df = data[['MARKET', 'CXR', 'DDATE', 'TYPE', 'FARE', 'DFLIGHT', 'CLASS', 'DATIME']]

first_button = tk.Button(text="Load File", command=first_button_function)
first_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

second_button = tk.Button(text="Cleaning Data", command=second_button_function)
second_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

and the error when trying to import a CSV

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-28-a860b1e96a6f>", line 12, in second_button_function
    df = data[['MARKET', 'CXR', 'DDATE', 'TYPE', 'FARE', 'DFLIGHT', 'CLASS', 'DATIME']]
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

I am probably assuming that the first button imports the DataFrame, but I may be wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you are calling the variable "data" in the "second_button_function". This variable is created in the previous function "first_button_function" by putting the file's data into it.
Since you are not parsing the variable outside of the first function, it is not accessible to the second function, or even to the rest of the program.
To correct this, you could either declare the variable "data" globally by using the keyword `global`:

```
def first_button_function():
file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=window,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
if file != None:
    global data
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
```

Or you could parse it manually by returning your variable from the first function and put as an argument of the functions that would require it. For instance:

```
def first_button_function():
file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=window,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
if file != None:
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
return data
```

Your second function function could then resemble:

```
def second_button_function(data):
df = data[['MARKET', 'CXR', 'DDATE', 'TYPE', 'FARE', 'DFLIGHT', 'CLASS', 'DATIME']]
```

But here I am not sure how exactly Tkinter calls its functions.
If you plan on building a more complex GUI, you might want to start looking into the Object-Oriented approach. It greatly facilitates the parsing of data through many functions (or "methods").

I hope this was helpful!
Best of luck in your coding adventures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer! It solved my error but another one arises:                                    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-42-7d5c1fd9bb36>", line 20, in second_button_function
    df = data[['MARKET', 'CXR', 'DDATE', 'TYPE', 'FARE', 'DFLIGHT', 'CLASS', 'DATIME']]
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not list                                                                 Do you have any idea why?Thx

Comment: Hi @Shold ! I am glad I was of any help!
Well, I think that in order to help you with this, I would need to have access to your data. It looks like you are trying to call the column names with a data structure which is expecting integers slices (like a numpy array). You could try to import your data using pandas and its function `pandas.read_csv()`, which usually does a pretty good job at recognising column names and dealing with data in general. Or if you know which integer corresponds to which column (e.g. data[0] would be data['MARKET']), then you could just use those.
Hope this helps! :)